# What's wrong with me to run the flink sample project(Frauddetection)?

Tags: apache-flink

I'm study apache-flink in it'stutorial,and i run it inside my IDEA,then a error occured  like this：
`enter code here` Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
`enter code here`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: `enter code here`org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/source/SourceFunction
`enter code here`at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
`enter code here`at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
`enter code here`at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)e
my jdk version is jdk1.8.0_291,jre version is jre1.8.0_331
is it related to this?

Comment: Please update your question to clarify which tutorial you are trying to run, and the specific errors you encountered.

Comment: I'm trying to run the Fraud Detection with the DataStream API sample project,and the error is like it i issued erarlier(Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again).And i know the reason now,i comment out the <scope>provided</scope> in maven pom.xml,then it worked. Anyway,Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to run a project like this one in IntelliJ, you will need to edit the run configuration to include this option:

```
Add dependencies with "provided" scope to classpath
```